# How to get Power of big number in decimal?

Tags: javascript

How to get big power of 2 in decimal or 
how to convert big exponential value into decimal value.

I want 2 to the power of 128 in decimal not exponential 
what I did till now

```
tofixed(+exponent)
```

which again given me the same value.

```
 var num =  Math.pow(2, 128);
```

Actual result = 3.402823669209385e+38
expected some decimal value not exponential value.

Comment: Do you mean scientific notation?

Comment: @JackBashford or standard form here in the UK :p

Comment: yeah you can say that.

Comment: JS doesn't support that natively - and what rounding would you like?

Comment: power of 2 would be an integer right. So where round came into picture

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), if implemented.

```js
var num =  BigInt(2) ** BigInt(128);

console.log(num.toString());
console.log(BigInt(2 ** 128).toString());
```

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap `num` in `BigInt()`?

Comment: hey thanks man its working. I was thinking BigInteger  a java concept.

Comment: @KrishnaKamal you really need to be careful about compatibility of using this if you're on a browser, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Browser_compatibility `BigInt` has not been adopted to the spec yet

Comment: @Kobe, right, that works as well (but this is strange.)

Comment: @NinaScholz how so?

Comment: @Kobe, don't know, maybe it has a different internal format.

Comment: So far Chrome is the only browser with official support for `BigInt`, Firefox has it hidden behind a flag.

Comment: @NinaScholz - The reason it works to just wrap the result in a `BigInt` is that the number is a power of 2, so it's held precisely even by IEEE-754, even at that magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

`3.402823669209385e+38` **is** a decimal number (in string form, because it's been output as a string). It's in scientific notation, specifically [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation). It's the number `3.402823669209385` times `100000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

If you want a **string** that isn't in scientific notation, you can use [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) for that:

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Math.pow(2, 128)));
```

**Note:** Although that number is **well** outside the range that JavaScript's number type can represent with precision in general (any integer above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` [9,007,199,254,740,991] may be the result of rounding), it's one of the values that *is* held precisely, even at that magnitude, because it's a power of 2. But operations on it that would have a true mathematical result that wasn't a power of 2 would almost certainly get rounded.

Answer (score -3):

I think the default power function won't be able to the results you want.
You can refer to the article below to understand how to create an Power function with big number by yourself.

Demo code is not JS but still quite understandable.

↓

[Writing power function for large numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-power-function-for-large-numbers/)